# Баг jQuery Selectric на iPad

Tags: javascript, css, ios, ipad

Я использую jQuery Selectric plugin для кастомизации select'а

```
$('select').selectric({
  disableOnMobile: false
});
```

Если я раскрываю select на iPad моя левая колонка с `position: fixed;` поднимается вверх

```
.left-column {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #F00;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Демо тут: http://output.jsbin.com/seleyi
Тестировал в browserstack iOS < 7 - нет проблем, iOS 8.3 - некоторые проблемы, iOS 9.1 наблюдается данный баг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это баг iOS 9, по-моему он тянется с iOS 8, но в 9 версию пришел частично. По возможности нужно сделать баг репорт.
Баг заключается с ***input'ом***, который имеет атрибут `readonly="readonly"`.
*Selectric* использует скрытый `input`:[image: Cкрин]

Что происходит:

1. При клике на `selectric-wrapper` запускается метод [`_open`](https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric/blob/master/src/jquery.selectric.js#L409).
2. Метод `_open` [переводит фокус](https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric/blob/master/src/jquery.selectric.js#L431) на скрытый `input.selectric-input`. Я не  разбирался зачем так делается. Возможно, легче повесить обработчики для нажатия клавиш именно на скрытый элемент. А обрабатывать такие события
   можно, когда на элементе находится фокус. Почему `input`? Если
   использовать другой элемент, то при нажатии на клавиши-стрелки, у
   нас будет скроллиться также сам документ. Поэтому, использовали
   `input`, хотя могу ошибаться. Может `input` лучше для читалок, т.е.
   использовали его для повышения accessibility.

И вот когда приходит фокус на `input`, не смотря на то, что он `readonly`, iOS (мне так кажется) пытается выделить пространство под клавиатуру.
Могу посоветовать простой workaround:

```
$(".selectric-input[readonly]").on("focus", function(evt) {
    this.blur();
});
```

Т.е. при фокусе сразу же от него избавляться, т.к. на айпадах невозможно двигаться по списку с помощью клавиатуры, то функциональность не должна быть нарушена.

Comment: Это работает! Спасибо!

Comment: @sglazkov, так работает или нет?

Comment: @sglazkov Хотя я вижу вы мой ответ перенесли на английский stackoverflow. Тогда не понятно зачем отменили "принятие ответа"

Comment: хотел набрать плюсиков в карму и тебе и мне, но да ладно, ещё раз огромное спасибо! Отличный, развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: @sglazkov, а я уже подумал, что решение нашли другое. Ну, а рейтинг вопроса/ответа для русского стека уже нормальный, вряд ли, апнут. Да, и проблема редкая. Кстати, Вы, скорее всего, будете следить за данным поведением, поэтому если исправят баг, отпишитесь.